# dojo How to dynamically change the title of the tab in tabContainer?

Tags: dojo

If I have made to the tab through the dojo,

mycode

```
var tab=new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        title:formCount,
        id:''+formCount,
        content:cont,
        class:'tab',
        closable: true,
        onClose:function(){
            return confirm('Relly want to remove?');
        }
    });
 dijit.byId('tabContainer').addChild(tab);
```

After the tab is created, i want to change the tab title dynamically through dijit/Dialog. 
but I don't know how it should be implemented,Please advise me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to create your own widget and extend from `dijit/layout/ContentPane`, for example:

```js
declare([ ContentPane ], {

});
```

Then you can add stuff to show a dialog, for example:

```js
declare([ ContentPane ], {
    btn: domConstruct.create("button", {
        innerHTML: "Change title",
    }),
    _createButton: function() {
        domConstruct.place(this.btn, this.domNode);
        on(this.btn, "click", lang.hitch(this, this._showDialog));
    },
    postCreate: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this._createButton();
        this._createDialog();
    }
});
```

The `postCreate` function is a part of the widget lifecycle in Dojo and is automatically executed when the widget is loaded. So, we use that to add a "Change title" button to the contentpane that, when being clicked calls a function `this._showDialog()` (that's what you can see in `this._createButton()`).

Of course, you also need to create a `dijit/Dialog` before you can actuall show one, so you could do something like:

```js
declare([ ContentPane ], {
    /** ... */
    dialog: null,
    editField: null,
    okBtn: null,
    _showDialog: function() {
        this.editField.value = this.title;
        this.dialog.show();
    },
    _createDialog: function() {
        var div = domConstruct.create("div");
        domConstruct.place(div, this.domNode);
        this.dialog = new Dialog({
            title: "Change title",
            content: ""
        }, div);

        this.editField = domConstruct.create("input", {
            type: "text"
        });
        this.okBtn = domConstruct.create("button", {
            innerHTML: "OK" 
        });
        domConstruct.place(this.editField, this.dialog.containerNode);
        domConstruct.place(this.okBtn, this.dialog.containerNode);
        on(this.okBtn, "click", lang.hitch(this, this._saveTitle));
    },
    /** .. */
});
```

What happens here is that we create a dialog with a simple textfield and a button (the OK button), all of that can be found in `this._createDialog()`.

In `this._showDialog()` you can see that I'm first changing the value of the textfield into the title of the contentpane. Then I show the dialog we made earlier.

Now all you have to do is read that value when the OK button is pressed:

```js
declare([ ContentPane ], {
    /** ... */
    _saveTitle: function() {
        this.set("title", this.editField.value);
        this.dialog.hide();
    },
    /** ... */
});
```

That's all you really need. You can find a working example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LE49K/

Comment: Thank you very much for an elaborate answer.^^